# "Conducted" or "done"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I am creating a report for my internship and have to write an introduction for my internship report.
What would be the appropriate word in the following sentence

"An internship was conducted", "An internship was done" or "An internship was performed"

which one should I use if I am referring to myself in the report ?

Comment: Moe context is needed, were you the internee or overseeing the internship?

Comment: @Peter please see my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that *you* were an internee. I feel like you should be saying *I [verb] an internship*, since you are reporting about yourself. In other words, it should be in the active voice.

I personally would say

> 1. I did an internship (over the summer, at [company name]).
> 2. I had an internship (over the summer, at [company name]).

I included "(over the summer, at [company name])" as an example. "Perform" and "conduct" sound strange here, probably since, as an internee, you aren't running/managing the internship. 
Here is some data on the matter. Notice that "perfomed" and "conducted" do not map.
[image]

Comment: @Max would you let me know how to search those information hit?

Comment: Why not "I [interned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interned) at company name"?

Comment: @JBL Click the image.

Comment: @ColleenV That didn't occur to me because I don't think I have ever heard anyone say "I interned at [company name]". In my experience, someone usually interns at a hospital. I'm in college (undergrad), and I usually/only hear have/had/did/doing. So it didn't occur to me. In my experience, it doesn't sound natural.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if it is a regional difference (AmE) or a profession difference (Engineering) or if I'm just ancient. I worked all the way through school and always referred to it as "interning". Maybe it was because it wasn't a formal internship program. I just went out and convinced people to hire me so I could get some relevant experience.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my opinion,

'Conducted' gives me feeling like "it is started"

'Done' and 'performed' do like "it is completed"

But 'performed' sounds a bit non sense because we perform a play or recitle like performance but not internship.